# Is there any way to make a canvas using only javascript and nothing else?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have had a lot of trouble finding a way how. everything tells me to use HTML, though I never learned it. if you know how, just show me an example WITHOUT HTML.

Comment: Numerous javascript/canvas libraries you can use. Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service

Comment: Without HTML you have no script tag...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.arc(150,150,100,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.stroke();
```

Create a canvas element using `createElement` and append it to body. FYI you need to add this script to a HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it wherever you like.maybe add it to a div instead of putting it to the body like I did. you can "Name of the element".appendChild(canvasElement)

```js
var canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas')

var body = document.querySelector("body")

body.appendChild(canvasElement)
```